# How to retrieve records from XML element with namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA_SDTC.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
<component>
<structuredBody>
  <component>
    <section>
      <templateId root="abs" />
      <title>A1</title>
      <text>
        <paragraph>Hello world!</paragraph>
      </text>
    </section>
  </component>
</structuredBody>
</component>
</Document>
```

I have the following code used to retrieve `paragraph`:

```
XDocument m_xmld = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/a.xml"));
var m_nodelist = m_xmld.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "section").
    Select(i => i.Element("text").Element("paragraph").Value).ToList();
```

Error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

However the following code works fine, but i want use above code.

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
var m_nodelist = m_xmld.Descendants(ns + "section").
       Select(i => i.Element(ns + "text").Element(ns + "paragraph").Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var m_nodelist = m_xmld.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "rows").
Select(u => u.Attribute("fname").Value).ToList();
```

update :

```
var m_nodelist = m_xmld.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "section").
Select(u => (string)u.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "paragraph")).ToList();
```

Comment: my xml file is too big, how to convert that to string to 'string x'

Comment: @SamieyMehdi now check

Answer (score 1):

`xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"` is your default namespace and so need to be referenced...

```
XNamespace ns="urn:hl7-org:v3";
m_xmld.Descendants(ns+"rows")....
```

---

**OR**

you can **avoid** the namespace itself

```
m_xmld.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "rows")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var m_nodelist = m_xmld.Root.Descendants("rows")
```

If you want to specify a namespace when selecting nodes you can try

```
var m_nodelist = m_xmld.Root.Descendants(XName.Get("rows", "urn:hl7-org:v3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly identified, you need to append the `namespace` to the node lookup.

```
XNamespace nsSys = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
var m_nodelist = m_xmld.Descendants(nsSys + "rows").Select(x => x.Attribute("fname").Value).ToList();
```